# Tokenize EVERY digit in a String number?

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I've got this bit of code here:

```
public class Project1 {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input a binary number");
        String binary = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(Conversion(binary)); 
    }

    public static int Conversion(String binary)
    {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(binary, " ");
        int n = st.countTokens() - 1; // Used as the power number in b^n for conversion
        int result = 0;
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            int binaryInt = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            result += binaryInt * (1 << n);
            n--;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

And it works beautifully... if the input has spaces in between the binary numbers. For example, if the input is `1 1 1 1`, then it will rightfully return `15`. Cool, but how do I change the tokenizer to not require spaces to split each digit? I tried doing `StringTokenizer(binary, "");` and `StringTokenizer(binary);`, but neither properly split each digit into it's own token.
You will notice that, while StringTokenizer obviously only works with Strings, I've converted the Strings into ints inside my conversion method before returning the result.

Comment: to get 2^n use `1 << n`, no need to use slow power

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc updated, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
    // remove everything that is not a digit
    String digitsOnly = binary.replaceAll("[^\\d]","");
    //iterate over every digit
    for(char digit:digitsOnly.toCharArray()) {
        int n = Character.getNumericValue(digit);
        // do stuff...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

@ Tony  I think you tried to add the ascii values of the digits  here 
for input value 10 
for first run

int binaryInt = binary.char(i) ; so binaryInt would get the value = 49(aski value of char '1')

hence result = 49*2 = 98

in second run

result = 98 + 48 *1 = 146

following function will serve your purpose, for input String "1101" , it returns 13

```
  public int getDecimal(String binaryString){
        //binaryString = "1101";
        int result = 0;
        int n = binaryString.length()-1;
        for(int i=0;i<binaryString.length();i++)
        {
            int num = binaryString.charAt(i);
            if(num>=48 && num <=57){
                result+=(num-48) * Math.pow(2, n)  ;
                n --;
            }

        }

        return result;
    }

   }
```

Comment: That's probably what is happening. I'm not good enough to try and resolve that issue, so I went with piet.t's solution, which returns the result as expected.

Comment: Does the function stated in above comment served your purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

If you get a string like `"10011010"`, you don't need a tokenizer, you can just iterate over the string and use `charAt`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char currentDigit = s.charAt(i);
    // Do stuff with the digit
}
```

Comment: somehow my math is wrong after changing to `charAt()`, even though I didn't change any of the computations...` This is what's happened http://puu.sh/83107.png